# Add a QWidget grammatically at runtime (qt)

Tags: c++, qt, runtime

I'm trying to add two QPushButton in another widget which derives from QPushButton at runtime. When I'm doing it while creating the widget, the inside QPushButton shows up fine, but when I try to modify the widget to make them show up, it doesn't work.

I tried to use .show() which work irregularly at best, and to modify the visibility directly with similar result.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const QString eleve::baseColor("background-color : #ffffff");
eleve::eleve(const QString & name,QWidget *parent):QPushButton(parent),grade(0),isdead(false){
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    setText(name);
    init_Boutton();
    setFixedSize(QSize(100,50));
    setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff;text-align:left;");
}

eleve::eleve(QWidget *parent):QPushButton(parent),grade(0),isdead(true){
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    setText("");
    setFixedSize(QSize(100,50));
    setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff;text-align:left;");
}

void eleve::init_Boutton(){
    plus=new QPushButton("+",this);
    moins=new QPushButton("-",this);


    moins->setFixedSize(30,this->size().height()/2+2);
    plus->setFixedSize(30,this->size().height()/2+2);

    int xPlus=this->pos().x()+size().width()-plus->size().width();
    int xMoins=this->pos().x()+size().width()-moins->size().width();
    int yMoins=this->pos().y()+size().height()-moins->size().height();
    moins->move(xMoins,yMoins);
    plus->move(xPlus,0);

    moins->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
    plus->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

    QObject::connect(plus, SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(plusFunc()));
    QObject::connect(moins, SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(moinsFunc()));

    plus->setStyleSheet("text-align:center;");
    moins->setStyleSheet("text-align:center;");
}

void eleve::Die(){
    isdead=true;
    setName("");
    setStyleSheet("background-color:#ffffff");
    delete plus;
    delete moins;
}

void eleve::Born(const QString name){
    isdead=false;
    if(name.isEmpty())
        AskForName();
    else
        setText(name);
    init_Boutton();
}


void eleve::AskForName(){
    setStyleSheet("background-color:#ffffff; text-align:left;");
    bool ok = false;
    QString tempName=QInputDialog::getText(this, "renommage","Nouveau nom:", QLineEdit::Normal, this->text(), &ok);
    if (ok){
        if(!tempName.isEmpty()){
            //setStyleSheet(tempStyle);
            changeColor();
            if(isdead)
                Born(tempName);
            else
                setText(tempName);
        }
    }
}
```

So, init_Button is called in both the constructor that makes a student alive, and in the Born function, but doesn't do make them appear in the Born function only.

In the following screenshot, you have want I want to achieve on the top side, and the result (which is empty) on the bottom side. The empty one are normal since I didn't ask them to born!

https://ibb.co/e0Q4a5

Comment: Widget positioning doesn't work that way, you should add them to a layout and set the layout on the parent, i.e container, widget. For the problem described, it's better to use QML + Qt Quick than QWidgets.

Comment: You shouldn't delete and recreate the buttons every time, either, hiding and showing them is enough.

Comment: That's actually a great idea i didn't think about, thanks!
And i am trying to do as much stuff i can from c++ to get familiarized with the qt library.

Comment: QML + Qt Quick form an important part of the Qt library, used alongside Qt Widgets as an alternative approach or as a tool for creating embedded, graphically rich, or otherwise non-standard interfaces. QML is just a graphical design tool, anyway, whereas JavaScript is an alternative to C++ for embedding a part of the logic into the QML package *or* for creating standalone interpreted applications without touching C++. I'd say, invest in learning the non-GUI part of Qt, i.e. networks, files, XML, etc. - that's Qt's main strength.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind, thank you !